# Replacing nested for loops for paired t-tests

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 factors and some numbers, with a structure similar to this:

```
year <- as.factor(rep(c(2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007,
        2007, 2007), 40))

seller <- rep(c("Alfred", "Betty", "Charles", "Debbie", "Ed"), 80)

region <- rep(c("North", "North", "North", "South", "South", "North", 
        "North", "South"), 50)

sale <- rnorm(400, mean = 60, sd = 10)  # Quick way to get fake data

data <- data.frame(year=year, seller=seller, region=region, sale=sale)
```

(The actual data frame I'm interested in is the equivalent of about 20,000 sales, over 13 years, and 6 regions, with 50 or so sellers, so I won't include it here.) I need to do pair-wise *t*-test comparisons for each pair of sellers, broken out by year and region. (E.g., for this sample data frame, I need 4 different sets of pair-wise comparisons: All the sellers compared against each other for 2006 and North, for 2007 and North, for 2006 and South, and for 2007 and South. Each set would have 10 pair-wise *t*-tests: Alfred with Betty, Alfred with Charles, etc.) Being an old C/C++ programmer (and relatively new R programmer), I could set up a couple of for loops, and loop over the year factor, and then the region factor, subset the data frame for that year and that region, and then perform & print/store all the pair-wise t-tests between the sellers.

However I'm trying figure out how to do this without the for-loops. I have tried to use one of the `apply`-family functions. I can write a function to perform the *t*-tests, and use `FUN = function`, but I can't seem to convert the two for-loops into a single INDEX for apply-family purposes. All my efforts so far, such as using "list(region, year)" as the index, result in the obvious error: "arguments must have the same length", not to mention that this particular approach won't apply BOTH filters simultaneously as desired. I've played a bit with `expand.grid()` to help, but I don't think that any resulting vectorization will get me what I want either.

Is there some way to do this without the for loops? I feel I'm missing something, but I can't find it; I'd be grateful for any help, even if the help says something like "`apply`-family is the wrong place to look and you should go to `data.table` or `dplyr`". (I am, however, especially interested in anything that can be done in base-R, but that's mostly because exploring base-R is the game I'm playing for now.)

Comment: Can you show the code that you ran that gave you that error? A split-apply strategy should work here. In your real code do you have your variables defined both as variables and as column names in your data.frame? It is always helpful to include the desired output for your sample input (and make your sample input reproducible by using `set.seed()` to set the random seed).

Comment: I'm sorry, but why would you **not** use a regression, with the appropriate interaction terms, for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: This is by no means good statistical practice. In fact, there is almost certainly a better way to do this sort of analysis. You are running 40 t-tests and if you apply any form of corrections, your p-value threshold would be very low. I am treating this just as a programming practice.

## Create data

```
year <- as.factor(rep(c(2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007), 40))
seller <- rep(c("Alfred", "Betty", "Charles", "Debbie", "Ed"), 80)
region <- rep(c("North", "North", "North", "South", "South", "North", "North", "South"), 50)
sale <- rnorm(400, mean = 60, sd = 10)  # Quick way to get fake data
data <- data.frame(year=year, seller=seller, region=region, sale=sale)
```

## Create data.frame of combinations

```
list.sellers.combn <- combn(c("Alfred", "Betty", "Charles", "Debbie", "Ed"), 2, simplify = FALSE)
df.region.year <- expand.grid(region = c("North", "South"), year = 2006:2007)
df.combn <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.sellers.combn, function(n) {
                                  df.region.year[,"seller1"] <- n[1]
                                  df.region.year[,"seller2"] <- n[2]
                                  df.region.year}))
```

## Run t.test

```
list.ttest.results <- lapply(1:nrow(df.combn), function(n) {
                             vec <- df.combn[n,]
                             df.data <- data[data[,"region"] == vec[,"region"] & data[,"year"] == vec[,"year"] & data[,"seller"] %in% unlist(vec[,c("seller1", "seller2")]),]
                             df.ttest <- df.data[,c("seller", "sale")]
                             result.ttest <- with(df.ttest, t.test(sale[seller == unique(seller)[1]], sale[seller == unique(seller)[2]]))
                             result.ttest})
```

Comment: Thanks; this is useful to me (and my learning); I hadn't thought about an *apply to combine and then another to compare. I agree that running this many t-tests is not an ideal approach, but as this probably isn't the only time I'm going to run into pair-wise comparisons of some sort, it will be a good trick to have played with.